# Best practice for having a class partnered with UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I'm creating a set of classes called `*Activity` which all inherit from the interface `IActivity` e.g.

```
  public interface IActivity
  {
    void StartActivity();
  }

  public class MyFirstActivity : IActivity
  {
    public int SomeVariable {get; set;}

    public MyFirstActivity(int someVariable)
    {
      SomeVariable = someVariable
    }

    public void StartActivity()
    {
      //some code to do stuff with SomeVariable
    }
  }
```

This is so I can create an list/array of `IActivity`s and run their `StartActivity()` methods.

Now what I want to do is to have a UserControl (for editing any variables graphically and ordering activites graphically) for each class which inherits from `IActivity`.

What is the best way to do this?

My thoughts are either:

1. Create a separate UserControl for each Activity and then create an instance of the activity in the UserControl's constructor... or...
2. Make each activity a UserControl which inherits from `IActivity`. The issue is with this is that I may want to not use the UserControl elements in other parts of the program, just using the actions that each performs and using a UserControl for this will surely use more resources when it's not needed...

Any thoughts?

**Edit:**
The idea is that each Activity has some properties which can be edited and each performs a distinct action which is performed when it's `StartActivity` is called.
Activities can either be performed in code via creating instances of activities and adding to a list. Loop through the list to perform each `StartActivity` in order.
Alternatively on a Form, UserControls of each activity can created and dragged round the form into the desired order by the user (which behind the scenes populates the list) and then clicks a Start button (which loops round the list calling each `StartActivity` in turn.

This would be using WinForms.

Comment: your purpose with the UserControl is somewhat unclear. can you elaborate a bit more? and is it in WinForms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go with your 1st thought. Take the *Activity as a Property(read-only) of the specific *UserContorl, and instantiate it through the UC constructor. Then You can set the Properties of the Activity visually through the UC.